# Read options of a menu bar for macOS application

Tags: python, automation, applescript

Is there a way to read in the options of a menu bar using Python and Applescript?

I'm trying to write a script where the user doesn't know what options exist in the menu bar so the script reads them from the application and displays them.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing the name of application process, you can read menu bar options with simple apple-script like this:

```
set processName to "Safari"

tell application "System Events" to tell process processName
    tell menu bar 1 to set menuBarItemNames to name of menu bar items
end tell

choose from list menuBarItemNames
```

NOTE:  the application should be running. Or, activate it in the beginning of the script:

```
tell application "Safari" to launch

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    repeat until menu bar 1 exists
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    tell menu bar 1 to set menuBarItemNames to name of menu bar items
end tell

choose from list menuBarItemNames
```